# Break out of for loop from a method called within loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration, break

I have a `List` of `jobs` that takes x number of steps (say 5). Each step must be successful to proceed, if any step fails, then a ticket must be raised and execution of current `job` must be forfeited and proceed with next `job`.

This is what i currently have (and it works like a charm).

```
for(Job aJob: jobs){
    // Step 1
    try{
        Obj objRet1 = method1();
        // use objRet1;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        raiseTicket(errMsg1,e);
        break;
    }

    // Step 2
    try{
    Obj objRet2 =   method2();
    // use objRet2;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        raiseTicket(errMsg2,e);
        break;
    }

    // Step 3
    try{
    Obj objRet3 = method3();
    // use objRet3;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        raiseTicket(errMsg3,e);
        break;
    }

    ...

    // Step 5
}
```

This is not very elegant and easily readable, IMO. I would like to condense it to something like below.

```
for(Job aJob: jobs){
    step1();
    step2();
    ..
    step5();
}

step1(){
    try{
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        raiseTicket(errMsg1,e);
        break;
    }
}

step2(){
}
...
```

Could someone throw some light on how to improve this program? Please note, returning a value or storing it in method argument also may not work, since, what am trying to achieve here is to avoid the boiler plate code that is required to `break` execution and neatly package them in a readable method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the steps throw a specific exception and let the loop code handle it!

With the following exception class

```
class StepExecutionException extends RuntimeException {
    StepExecutionException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    void raiseTicket() {
        // Code that raises the ticket ...
        // The message can be retrieved with getMessage().
        // The cause can be retrieved with getCause().
    }
}
```

you can easily implement the steps with that code:

```
void step1() {
    try {
        ...
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new StepExecutionException("Step 1", e);
    }
}
```

And now your loop code looks like:

```
for (Job aJob : jobs) {
    try {
        step1();
        step2();
        ...
    } catch (StepExecutionException see) {
        see.raiseTicket();
    }
}
```

Comment: i like this solution. i see that Dat Nguyen also suggested same answer. so looks like its a common problem and there is a design pattern to solve it.

Comment: may i ask, why RuntimeException is used and not a checked exception?

Comment: `StepExecutionException` is a checked exception :) See this SO thread for some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Comment: You can make it checked or unchecked - whatever you prefer. Joshua Bloch's book "Effective Java" is now somewhat aged. And there is a long-going discussion whether checked exceptions should be used at all. I personally prefer to only use unchecked exceptions. The main reason is to not clutter method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `break` will not interrupt the current iteration but the whole loop. You need to use `continue` to achieve that. But since an exception that is thrown will skip over the remaining steps, in this case you don't need any extra statement.

Why not use something like this?

```
// create list with errorMessages in the following order: errMesFor1, errMesFor2,..., errMesFor5
List<String> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
messageList.add(errMesFor1);
messageList.add(errMesFor2);
messageList.add(errMesFor3);
messageList.add(errMesFor4);
messageList.add(errMesFor5);

for(Job aJob: jobs){
    // create list that holds successfully created objects 
    List<Obj> objList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
            Obj objRet1 = method1();
            // use objRet1;
            list.add(objRet1);
            Obj objRet2 = method2();
            // use objRet2;
            list.add(objRet2);
            Obj objRet3 = method3();
            // use objRet3;
            list.add(objRet3);
            Obj objRet4 = method4();
            // use objRet4;
            list.add(objRet4);
            Obj objRet5 = method5();
            // use objRet5;
            list.add(objRet5);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            // retrieve message for the first element that was not successfully added to the object list, hence the one that threw error
            raiseTicket(messageList.get(objList.size()),e);
        }
```

This way, you only have to write the `try-catch` block once.

It is also nice to organize the messages in a `list` (or you could even write a custom `wrapper class` over a list).

The only extra thing that is required is the object list so that you can easily find the object that threw exception.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. i wanted to say `continue` but i typed `break` by mistake

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is throw a checked exception in each of the step if an error occurs, and then catch the checked exception in the for loop. Something like this:

```
class StepException extends Exception {...}

for (Job aJob: jobs) {
  try {
     step1();
     step2();
     ...
     step5();
  } catch (StepException se) {
     // do something, e.g. print error to console
     // the for loop will keep going when this occurs
  }
}

step1() throws StepException {
   try {
      ...
   } catch (Exception e) {
      raiseTicket(...);
      throw new StepException(e);
   }
}

// similar to step2(), ..., step5()
```

Comment: i like the solution. but since Seelenvirtuose provided the same answer first, am accepting his answer.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be:

```
for (Job job : jobs) {
    AtomicInteger step = new AtomicInteger();
    try {
        Obj result = executeJob(step, () -> method1());
        // do something with result
        result = executeJob(step, () -> method2());
        // do something with result
        result = executeJob(step, () -> method3());
        // do something with result
    } catch (Exception e) {
        raiseTicket(errorMessages.get(step.get()), e);
    }
}

private Obj executeJob(AtomicInteger step, Supplier<Obj> supplier) {
    step.incrementAndGet();
    return supplier.get();
}
```

while `errorMessages` is a `Map<Integer, String>`.

Answer (score 0):

**As per JAVA basics No One Can Use break outside loop or switch**

> As Methods are represent stack memory entries you can't break loop from stack memory in case where loop is in another stack entry and method is in other stack entry.